# LiveData update values when field of object change

Tags: android-databinding, android-livedata, android-mvvm, mutablelivedata

Today I'm trying to use a LiveData (MutableLiveData) object to have some dynamics values. (in MVVM pattern)

I used a model object like this:

```
public class Object {
    private String name;
    private float internalvalue;
    private float in1;
    private float out1;
    private float out2;

    public Object(String name, float internalvalue){
        this.name = name;
        this.internalvalue = internalvalue;
    }

    public float getOut1(){
        return this.out1;
    }

    public float getOut2(){
        return this.out2;
    }

    public void setIn1(float in1){
        this.in1 = in1;

    }

    private void performSomething(float internalvalue, float in1){
        SubClassSingleton.performSomething(internalvalue, in1, new SubClassSingletonListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(float out1, float out2){
                this.out1 = out1;
                this.out2 = out2;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I use a ViewModel like this:

```
public class MainViewModel {
    public MutableLiveData<Object> obj;

    public MainViewModel(){
        this.obj = new MutableLiveData<>();
        this.obj.postValue(new Object("Name", 50.0f);
    }
}
```

In MainFragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MainViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        MainFragmentBinding binding = MainFragmentBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

And in View:

```
<layout ...
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="app.example.MainViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        ...>
        <EditText
            android:text="@={viewModel.obj.in1}"
            .../>
        <TextView
            android:text="@{viewModel.obj.out1}"
            .../>
        <TextView
            android:text="@{viewModel.obj.out2}"
            .../>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I'd like to update my view when the values (out1, out2) of my model are updated (when the calculation is performed).

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You need to make your model class extend BaseObservable.

```java
public class Object extends BaseObservable {
    private String name;
    private float internalvalue;
    private float in1;
    private float out1;
    private float out2;

    public Object(String name, float internalvalue) {
        this.name = name;
        this.internalvalue = internalvalue;
    }

    public float getOut1() {
        return this.out1;
    }

    public void setOut1(float out1) {
        this.out1 = out1;
        notifyChange();
    }

    public float getOut2() {
        return this.out2;
    }

    public void setOut2(float out2) {
        this.out2 = out2;
        notifyChange();
    }

    public void setIn1(float in1) {
        this.in1 = in1;
    }

    private void performSomething(float internalvalue, float in1) {
        SubClassSingleton.performSomething(internalvalue, in1, new SubClassSingletonListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(float out1, float out2) {
                setOut1(out1);
                setOut2(out2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in View, you cannot bind float directly to view. It has to be string, so bind like this:

```xml
<layout ...
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="app.example.MainViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        ...>
        <EditText
            android:text='@={""+viewModel.obj.in1}'
            .../>
        <TextView
            android:text='@{""+viewModel.obj.out1}'
            .../>
        <TextView
            android:text='@{""+viewModel.obj.out2}'
            .../>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Another possibility is `android:text="@{Float.toString(viewModel.obj.in1)}"`.